# Create a Macro the deletes rows based on a certain criteria

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

there can you help me write a macro that deletes all the rows that does not contain for example 'AUDJPY'
I made a Macro but it does not seem to be working. So I just want all rows that contain AUDJPY. If I do not need to use a macro and there is a easier way please assist

[I excluded the code as it is not accepted by stack overflow]

Get rows of information that are related or contain for example AUDJPY and delete all the other rows that does not contain "AUDJPY". I will like to do the same for other pairs such as EURCAD ect

Comment: Can I ask you about the detail of `[I excluded the code as it is not accepted by stack overflow]`?

Comment: Thank you for the response. The code: 'Function DeleteRows() 
 
  Dim lastRow As Long 
  lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 
 
  For i = lastRow To 1 Step -1 
    If Cells(i, 5).Value <> "audjpy" Then 
      Rows(i).Delete 
    End If 
  Next 

End Function